# No matching function call for template specialization of const char*

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to learn the template specialization for C++ language, coming across this situation I can't solve myself. Codes below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
size_t count(const vector<string> &, const char* const &);

template <typename T>
size_t count(const vector<T>& v, const T& find) {
  size_t c = 0;
  for (auto ele : v) {
    if (ele == find)
      ++c;
  }
  return c;
}

template <>
size_t count(const vector<double> &v, const double &find) {
  size_t c = 0;
  for (auto ele : v) {
    if (abs(ele - find) < 0.0001)
      ++c;
  }
  return c;
}

template <>
size_t count(const vector<const char*> &v, const char* const &find) {
  size_t c = 0;
  for (auto ele : v) {
    if (strcmp(ele, find) == 0)
      ++c;
  }
  return c;
}

size_t count(const vector<string> &v, const char* const &find) {
  size_t c = 0;
  for (auto ele : v) {
    if (strcmp(ele.c_str(), find) == 0)
      ++c;
  }
  return c;
}

int main() {
  vector<double> vd{0.1, 0.1, 0.2};
  cout << count(vd, 0.1) << endl;
  vector<string> vs{"I", "you", "I"};
  cout << count(vs, "I") << endl;
  vector<const char*> vc{"I", "you", "I"};
  cout << count(vc, "I") << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling this code, `cout << count(vc, "I") << endl;` will report error about not  finding a matching function call.

However, I deliberately declare a specialization for this function call, namely `template <> size_t count(const vector<const char*> &v, const char* const &find)`

What is wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Having a reference to a pointer is pretty much useless unless you are supposed to modify the pointer, which you are not doing (which is why you marked it as a constant pointer I guess? Which makes it even more useless actually). Just declare the argument as plain `const char *`.

Comment: As for your problem, when asking about build errors it helps (a lot!) if you include the actual errors you get (in full, complete, and unedited) in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way specializations work is: first deduction happens against the primary template, and then any specializations are considered. When you call `count(vc, "I")`, we perform deduction on

```
template <typename T>
size_t count(const vector<T>& v, const T& find)
```

which will deduce `const char*` for the first `T`, but `char[2]` for the second `T`. Since those don't match, deduction fails. It doesn't matter what your specializations are (which are wrong anyway, for the same reason).

---

Instead of specializing and using the same `T` in both places, simply provide two overloads:

```
template <class Container, class ELem>
size_t count(Container const& c, Elem const& elem); // uses operator==

template <class Container, class UnaryPredicate>
size_t count(Container const& c, UnaryPredicate f); // uses f()
```

That way, you can write:

```
count(vd, [](double d){return abs(d-0.1) < 0.00001;});
count(vc, [](const char* p){ return strcmp(p, "I") == 0; });
```

without added duplication.

Comment: Or, you know, [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)

Comment: Thank you for the response. In that case, why can't a C-style string literal be deduced as the type of `const char *`. In template type deduction, array to pointer conversion is allowed and implicit.

Comment: @ShaunZiqinRong Because the conversion comes later.  The actual type of a string literal is a `const char[n]` and that is what the template uses.

Comment: @NathanOliver Understood. The conversion happens for parameters passed to the function. Thanks a lot for replying.

Comment: @NathanOliver Heh, the fix to `[2]` is correct but the non-`const` part I got right the first time. `const T&` so `T` is just `char[2]`. Thanks though.

Comment: @Barry Of course.  I forgot it was `const T` in the parameter.  Sorry for that.

Comment: @NathanOliver No worries. Appreciate the fix.